# express jwt - Authentication Middleware Issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt, express-jwt

I'm setting up a Token based authentication using express-jwt but the middleware which sends an error message if the token is missing or invalid is not working.

**index.js file**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const {getAllUsers: findUser} = require('../controllers/users');
const {register: registerUser, login: loginUser} = require('../controllers/authentication');
const jwt = require('express-jwt');
const auth = jwt({
secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
userProperty: 'auth'
});
// users
router
.route('/users', auth)
.get(findUser);

// registration
router
.route('/register')
.post(registerUser);

// login
router
.route('/login',auth)
.post(loginUser);

module.exports = router;
```

**Users Controller:**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = mongoose.model('Users');

let getAllUsers = (req,res) => {

 User.find((err,user)=>{
  if(user){
      res
          .status(200)
          .json({user})
    }
   });
};

module.exports = {
   getAllUsers
};
```

**app.js file:**

```
require('dotenv').load();
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const favicon = require('serve-favicon');
const logger = require('morgan');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const passport = require('passport');

require('./app_api/models/db');
require('./app_api/config/passport');

const index = require('./app_server/routes/index');
const apiRoutes = require('./app_api/routes/index');


const app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'app_server','views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev')); 


   app.use(bodyParser.json());
   app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
   app.use(cookieParser());
   app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));



 app.use(passport.initialize());

   app.use('/', index);
   app.use('/api', apiRoutes);

   //error handlers
  // catch unauthorised errors
  app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    if (err.name === 'UnauthorizedError') {
        res.status(401).send('invalid token...');
    }
});
// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  const err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});


module.exports = app;
```

I am setting the middleware on `users` route which returns a list of all users. But only authorized users should be able to access that list.

The middleware does not seem to be working as I can still get the users list even if I do not send a token.
What am I doing wrong?

**Please Note:** Im using POSTMAN to test this.

---

**Update (Figured out the problem):**

It was a very simple fix can't believe I didn't see it before. The issue was where I was placing `auth`.

I was placing it after the `route` url like so:

```
router
 .route('/users', auth)
 .get(findUser);
```

When the correct way of doing this is:

```
router
 .route('/users')
 .get(auth, findUser);
```

The above fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

According to README in the repository, you should check if `user` property is present in the request.

> The JWT authentication middleware authenticates callers using a JWT.
>   If the token is valid, req.user will be set with the JSON object
>   decoded to be used by later middleware for authorization and access
>   control.

Your `findUser` function should handle it

```
function findUser(req, res) {
  if (!req.user) return res.sendStatus(401);
  // do something else
}
```

You might also consider changing `userProperty` to `requestProperty`.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Shouldn't the error handling be done by the middleware? Thats my main issue the middleware is not functioning. I should be getting a `invalid token....` error message but Im not.

Comment: Can you show how you've implemented this route in your app? What you've provided looks incomplete. It might be an issue with route configuration.

Comment: Please see my updated question. I've added my `app.js` file, `index.js` file and the controller file. I hope this helps.

Comment: I fixed the issue. I was being an idiot and made a stupid mistake. Thank you for trying to help me though. its much appreciated. :)

Comment: I was placing `auth` at the wrong place. I've updated my question and added my solution there.

Comment: ooooooooooh, I didn't notice that :D